# Verification of Stokes’ theorem

Tags: stokes-theorem, electromagnetism

Consider the vector field $$\vec{F}=-\frac{y}{x^2+y^2}\hat{i}+\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}\hat{j}$$. Calculating the curl of the vector field I am getting zero. But when I am calculating the line integral along the unit circle I am getting $2\pi$. What’s wrong? Is Stokes’ theorem not valid here?

Comment: What is the curl at the origin?

Comment: Is it something related to delta function?

Comment: You have the right idea. Strictly speaking it doesn't exist: even $\vec F$ isn't defined at the origin, so Stokes' theorem doesn't apply. But you can play a bit fast and loose and try to make the field well-behaved by multiplying it by $r/\epsilon$ for $r=\sqrt{x^2 + y^2} < \epsilon$ so it goes to zero at the origin, and then integrate the curl. You can then let $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$ to recover the original field and see what that says about the curl at the origin.

Comment: Thank you!! got it

Comment: The man's name was "George Stokes" not "Stoke"